# SQL How many of a counted row is in another counted row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been stuck on how to write a particular query for the following question:

> How many employees are in how many businesses?

My end result should look like this:

| EmployeeId Count | BusinessId Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 23473423 |
| 2 | 56245764 |
| 3 | 834456 |

So there are 23473423 businesses that have 1 employee, 23473423 businesses that have 2 employees, etc.

I have a table with a list of items including EmployeeId and BusinessId. A BusinessId can connect to many EmployeeIds.
So far I have the following code to get me employees per business

```
Select BusinessId,
    Count(EmployeeId) as EIdCount
From Table
Group by BusinessId
```

Which gets me me a list of BusinessIds and how many EmployeeIds are attached to it.

| BusinessId | EIdCount |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 2 |
| 24 | 5 |
| 25 | 1 |
| 26 | 3 |

But now I need to figure out how to further group it to where the BusinessId's can be grouped by the Grouped Counted Employee Ids. I've looked at subqueries, having by, and group but I am still at a loss how to progress this without running into an error.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Please show some sample data that would be used to produce the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
Select EIdCount, Count(BusinessId)
From (
  Select BusinessId,
      Count(EmployeeId) As EIdCount
  From Table
  Group by BusinessId
) A
Group By EIdCount
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a subquery:

```
select
    EIdCount,count(BusinessId) as [BusinessId Count]
from
(
--your original query/start
    Select BusinessId,
        Count(EmployeeId) as EIdCount
    From Table
    Group by BusinessId
--your original query/end
)t
group by EIdCount
```